# Registro llave foranea

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Buen dia

Para empezar trabajo en laravel 5.5, tengo dos tablas, una donde tengo un usuario administrativo, y otra donde se agregan usuarios de votacion, cuando registro un usuario de votacion me aperece este error,

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a
 default value (SQL: insert into usuarios ('nombre', 'apellido',
 'cedula', 'telefonos', 'direccion', 'barrio', 'lugar_votacion',
 'mesa_votacion', 'email', 'ciudad', 'updated_at', 'created_at') values
 (angelica, sarmiento, 4564654, 3274865, cra 27, cuba, ormaza, 30,
 sergioad@gmail.com, pereira, 2018-09-27 23:54:31, 2018-09-27
 23:54:31))
```

`user_id` es la llave foranea que viene de la tabla del admin, el error es obvio, a pesar de que estoy en sesion y el usuario existe no se manda ningun valor a ese campo, la pregunta es...

como puedo hacer para que ese campo aparezca con el id del usuario que esta en sesion y esta registrando esta informacion?

Comment: El mensaje de error habla por sí mismo. En tu consulta SQL no estás indicando el campo `user_id` (sólo los campos `'nombre', 'apellido',
 'cedula', 'telefonos', 'direccion', 'barrio', 'lugar_votacion',
 'mesa_votacion', 'email', 'ciudad', 'updated_at', 'created_at'`) y éste es obligatorio en tu tabla por no tener valor por defecto. ¿Podrías compartir el código PHP para indicarte cómo podrías agregarlo?. Por cierto, aparecen una buena cantidad de campos de texto sin escapar. ¿Podría ser una errata o los estás enviando así? En cualquier caso, sin código, no podemos ayudarte más.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo arregle, solo asigne un valor al campo por medio del metodo auth(), eres muy amable amigo